# Where to setup my actors in a play app?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I want to setup my actors inside of a play app, for example, I have an actor that will poll a message queue or run every x minutes.

I renamed the actor system in my play app, so I now how to get the actor system.

```
play.akka.actor-system = "myAkka"
```

I know I can get the actor system using dependency injection inside of a controller but I don't need it at the controller level, I need to do this when my application starts outside of the request/response level.

Answer (score 0):

One of the the way is to crate your actors in an eager singleton.

Create singleton like this:

```
package com.app;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ActorBootstrap {

    private ActorRef somaActor;

    @Inject
    public ActorBootstrap(ActorSystem system) {
        // Craete actors here: somaActor = system.actorOf()
    }

    public ActorRef getSomaActor() {
        return somaActor;
    }

}
```

Define the singleton as eager in guice module as follows:

```
package com.app;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ActorBootstrap.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings for details.

Register your module with Play (add the following line to application.conf):

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.app.AppModule"
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings for details.

Comment: also check https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#dependency-injecting-actors

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of a scheduled actor implementation.

The actor schedules some periodic work:

```
public class ScheduledActor extends AbstractActor {  
    // Protocol  
    private static final String CANCEL = "cancel";  
    private static final String TICK = "tick"; 
    // The first polling in 30 sec after the start  
    private static final int TICK_INTERVAL_SEC = 90;
    private static final int TICK_INTERVAL_SEC = 90;
    private Cancellable scheduler;

    public static Props props() {  
        return Props.create(ScheduledActor.class, ()->new ScheduledActor());  
    }

    public ScheduledActor() {  
        receive(ReceiveBuilder  
            .matchEquals(TICK, m -> onTick())
            .matchEquals(CANCEL, this::cancelTick)  
            .matchAny(this::unhandled)  
            .build());  
      }

      @Override  
      public void preStart() throws Exception {  
          getContext().system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(  
                 Duration.create(ON_START_POLL_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS),  
                 self(),  
                 TICK,  
                 getContext().dispatcher(),  
                 null);  
      }

      @Override  
      public void postRestart(Throwable reason) throws Exception {  
          // No call to preStart  
      }

      private void onTick() {  
          // do here the periodic stuff
          ...
          getContext().system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(  
                 Duration.create(TICK_INTERVAL_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS),  
                 self(),  
                 TICK,  
                 getContext().dispatcher(),  
                 null);  
    }

    public void cancelTick(String string) {  
        if (scheduler != null) {  
            scheduler.cancel();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The actor life-cycle handler creates and actor and cancels it upon application stop:

```
public class ScheduledActorMonitor {  
    private ActorRef scheduler;  
    private ActorSystem system;  

    @Inject  
    public ScheduledActorMonitor(ActorSystem system, ApplicationLifecycle lifeCycle) {  
        this.system = system;  
        initStopHook(lifeCycle);  
    } 

    public void startPolling() {  
        scheduler = system.actorOf(ScheduledActor.props();            
    }

    public void cancelTick() {  
        if (scheduler != null) {  
            scheduler.tell(HelloScheduler.CANCEL, null);  
        }  
    } 

    private void initStopHook(ApplicationLifecycle lifeCycle) {  
        lifeCycle.addStopHook(() -> {  
            cancelTick();  
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);  
        });  
    }  
}
```

The StartupHandler is injected as a singleton; it receives in the constructor an actor monitor and starts polling:

```
@Singleton  
public class StartupHandler {  
    @Inject  
    public StartupHandler(final ScheduledActorMonitor schedularMonitor) {  
        schedularMonitor.startPolling();  
    }  
}
```

The StartupHandler is registered for injection by the default module Play Module:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {  
    @Override  
    public void configure() {  
        bind(StartupHandler.class).asEagerSingleton();  
    }  
}
```

You can read more [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/10/scheduling-asynchronous-task-in-play.html).